# Add button to QTableWidget cell alongside with entry

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a `QTableWidget` and one column of it is for specifying file path. I want to provide user with two options, writing the path, or specifying it using `QFileDialog`. When I added a button as cell widget, it covered whole cell and the entry disappeared.

```
QPushButton *browseButton = new QPushButton("...", tableWidget);
tableWidget->setCellWidget(rowCount, 3, browseButton);
```

How can I insert `QPushButton` or `QAction` with `QIcon` alongside with entry?

Comment: I think there should be simpler method, I only need an icon to be displayed right after cell's entry

Comment: If there is, I cannot find it in `QTableWidgetItem`. And setting cell widget is not an option, since you want to use `QTableWidget::item`.

Comment: Well would it work if you had a widget that contained a QLineEdit for the user to write the path and a QPushButton for opening the file dialog? Then you set that as the cell widget.