# How do I create an item delegate with buttons?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

[image]

> A list with 3 columns. First column for show/hide, second for the model name and the third for lock/unlock that will only appear when the item is clicked.

How do you create something like this using QTableWidget and QStyledItemDelegate? I have been looking at the documentations and some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43092922/10344668) and I still find it hard to understand.

Comment: If it's 3 columns, that means the lock icon is from a column of the data? So in the delegate which draws that column, you only want the lock shown if the item is selected, right? What's the role of the lock -- is that the a decoration role, a display role (eg. with an icon path), or... ? An MRE could be helpful. Especially because it looks like 2 columns in the image (icon in 2nd column).